# Python: how to return a total into a list of tuples of integers?

Tags: python-3.x, loops

I've been doing an exercise in python which is a coin flip. I tried to use a function as its supposed to be on the instruction.

I've having a hard time to return the total number of heads and tails as a tuple of integers.And i need to repeat this function 20 times. I am not sure if i will put the for loop before the conditional statements or after. Can someone please help me do it?

this is my code

```
import random

coin = random.randint(0,1)
heads = 0
tails = 0
total = 0

    def coinFlip():
        if coin == 0:
            print ("Heads")
            heads += 1
            total += 1
    
        elif coin == 1:
            print ("Tails")
            tails += 1
            total += 1
```

Comment: You have only generated one random number. That means the coin will always be the same.

Comment: What were the exact instructions?

Comment: Try something like `def flip_coin(): return random.randint(0, 1) == 0 ? "Heads" : "Tails"`. If you're going to name it "flip coin", that's what you should be doing, and that's **all** you should be doing inside that function.

Comment: Write a Python function coinFlip() that will first randomly choose 0 or 1.
If 0 is chosen print "heads", if 1 is chosen, print "tails". Do this using conditional statements.
Add a loop so that the function repeats this 20 times.
Create a running total for the number of heads, and the number of tails.
Have your function return the total number of heads and the total number of tails, as a tuple of integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the description in your comment, it looks like you need to move most of your code into the `coinFlip` function, and add a loop to do 20 flips:

```
import random

def coinFlip():
    heads = 0
    tails = 0
    for _ in range(20):
        coin = random.randint(0,1)
        if coin == 0:
            print ("heads")
            heads += 1
        elif coin == 1:
            print ("tails")
            tails += 1
    return (heads, tails)
        
print(coinFlip())
```

Sample output:

```
tails
heads
tails
tails
heads
heads
tails
heads
heads
tails
tails
heads
tails
heads
tails
heads
heads
heads
heads
tails
(11, 9)
```

Comment: @prvrlx since you don't need the variables outside the function, it's generally better to only declare and use them inside it, although the code would still work with them declared outside it.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

def simulate():
    total = 0
    heads = 0
    tails = 0

    while total <= 20:
        coin = random.randint(0,1)
        if coin == 0:
            print ("Heads")
            heads += 1
        elif coin == 1:
            print ("Tails")
            tails += 1
        total += 1
    
    return (heads, tails)

heads, tails = simulate()
print(f"Number of Heads - {heads}")
print(f"Number of Tails - {tails}")
```

Output:

```
Tails
Tails
Tails
Heads
Heads
Tails
Tails
Heads
Heads
Heads
Heads
Tails
Heads
Tails
Heads
Heads
Heads
Heads
Tails
Heads
Tails
Number of Heads - 12
Number of Tails - 9
```